# Bernoulli First Order ODE

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to know if my answer is equivalent to the one in the back of the book. if so what was the algebra? if not then what happened?

$$x^2y'+ 2xy = 5y^3$$

$$y' = -\frac{2y}{x} + \frac{5y^3}{x^2}$$

$n = 3$

$v = y^{-2}$

$-\frac{1}{2}v'=y^{-3}$

$$\frac{-1}{2}v'-\frac{2}{x}v = \frac{5}{x^2}$$

$$v'+\frac{4}{x}v=\frac{-10}{x^2}$$

this is now a first order linear ODE where:

$$y(x)=\frac{1}{u(x)}\int u(x)q(x)$$

$u(x)=e^{4\int\frac{1}{x}}=x^4$

$q(x) = \frac{-10}{x^2}$

$$\frac{1}{x^4}\int x^4 \frac{-10}{x^2}=\frac{1}{x^4}\frac{-10x^{2+1}}{2+1}+C$$

which leaves us with :

$$\frac{1}{y^2} = \frac{-10}{3x}+x^{-4}C$$

naturally

$$y^2= \frac{1}{\frac{-10}{3x}+x^{-4}C}$$

The book states the answer as being:

$$y^2= \frac{x}{2+Cx^5}$$

Comment: You made a mistake somewhere. Note that the equation is just $$(x^2y)'=5y^3$$ it's separable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You switched one sign too many in
$$
-\frac12v'+\frac2xv=\frac5{x^2}
$$
Then
$$
\left(\frac{v}{x^4}\right)'=\frac{v'}{x^4}-\frac{4v}{x^5}=-\frac{10}{x^6}
\implies
\frac{v}{x^4}=\frac2{x^5}+C
$$
etc.

Answer (score 1):

Write:$$(x^2y)' = 5y^3$$ Now let $z=x^2y$ then we get $$z' = {5z^3\over x^6}\implies {z'\over z^3} = 5x^{-6}$$
So after integrating both sides we get $$ -{z^{-2}\over 2} = -x^{-5}+c'\implies {1\over 2x^4y^2} = {1-c'x^5\over x^5}$$

So $$ y^2 = {x\over 2+cx^5}$$
where $c=-2c'$.

Answer (score 0):

You made a sign mistake here:
$$\frac{-1}{2}v'+\frac{2}{x}v = \frac{5}{x^2}$$
And also
$$\left (\frac 1 {y^2} \right )'=-2\frac {y'}{y^3}$$
$$\implies v'=-2\frac {y'}{y^3}$$
Another way:
$$x^2dy+ 2xydx - 5y^3dx=0$$
$$d(x^2y) - 5y^3dx=0$$
$$\frac {dx^2y}{(x^2y)^3} - 5\frac {dx}{x^6}=0$$
$$- \frac {1}{2(x^2y)^2} +\frac {1}{x^5}=C$$